# Copy a page created in sharepoint designer to another server where there is no designer

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer, custom-lists

i have a custom list in my sharepoint 2010 site.
Done some customization such as adding parameters and a filter.
Now my problem is that I have to use this customized list in another server where there is no designer.How can this be achieved.Please help me in this,thanks

Comment: As SharePoint use a lot of unique IDs in pages (list's ID especially), I'm afraid you will have to recreate most of the customization by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install SharePoint Designer on your machine and access any site that you have permissions for. SPD does not live on a server.

Re the list: in the list settings click "Save list as template", then in the Site Collection go to the Site Actions > Site Settings > Solutions. Download the solution file. Browse to the other server's site, upload to that site collection's solution gallery and activate the solution. Now you can create a list from that list template on the other server's sites.